# regression on images using keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, regression, kaggle

I want to use images to predict positions of hands, face, and steering.

[image: Car Driver]

source: [Kaggle](http://ggle.com/c/state-farm-distracted-driver-detection)

to do this I have manually labelled this dataset as follows

```
    image   Head_x  Head_y  left_hand_x left_hand_y steering_wheel_x steering_wheel_y   right_hand_x    right_hand_y
    0   img_56.jpg  192 178 461 126 443 219 587 321
    1   img_63.jpg  333 135 636 56  581 171 637 383
    2   img_118.jpg 242 134 539 161 540 240 633 398
    3   img_120.jpg 163 132 479 110 440 213 592 304
    4   img_138.jpg 192 185 514 105 490 213 588 407
```

I am using kerasRegressor to train the Neural Network Model. Input to neural net should be images like above and 8 output values i.e. X and Y coordinates of each position. but I don't know how to use these images as input and train the model.

```
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=100, verbose=False)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=kfold)
```

I have done this to seperate input from output.

```
X = data["image"].values
data.drop("image",axis=1, inplace=True)
Y = data.values
```

but obviously I need to replace name of image with content of image. How do I do it? will RGB values of each pixel in image work ?

Answer (score 1):

In `keras` you can load an image with:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img

img_path = 'img_56.jpg'
img = load_img(img_path)  # this is a PIL image
x = img_to_array(img)
```

[Source](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html)

This will give you a tensor of shape `(channels, height, width)`, where `channels` is typically `3` for an `RGB` image.